# Jest: stuck on [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block,

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to load a file and search for specific terms within it. If the file doesn't have any of the terms, then I need to throw an error message. This all appears to work in the code, but when I created my Jest test cases, I started getting the message:

> [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). ...

Everything is wrapped in a try/catch block, so the message has no meaning to me and I'm guessing it is probably a problem with what I'm doing in Jest. I'm new to Jest testing so any help would be appreciated. I've isolated the test so, I know this is the one causing issues.

The test case:

```
test('missing functions in file', () => {
  const input = 'no functions here'
  jest
    .spyOn(fs, 'readFile')
    .mockImplementation(() =>
      Promise.resolve(Buffer.from(input, 'utf-8').toString())
    )

  expect(async () => await loadFunctionsFromFile()).toThrowError(
    `No functions found in file.\nThey must have the format of '/* fn: */function' or '/* fn: */ function'.`
  )
})
```

My code being tested:

```
export async function loadFunctionsFromFile() {
  try {
    let flieText = await getFnTextFromFile(
      jsonTransformConfig.providedFunctionsFile
    )
    flieText += await getFnTextFromFile(jsonTransformConfig.addOnFunctionsFile)

    return flieText
  } catch (err: any) {
    throw errorHandler(err, 'loadFunctionsFromFile')
  }
}

async function getFnTextFromFile(fileName: string) {
  try {
    const fileText = await tryToGetFileText(fileName)
    const functionsText = tryToRemoveExtraText(fileText)

    return functionsText
  } catch (err: any) {
    throw errorHandler(err, 'getFnTextFromFile')
  }
}

async function tryToGetFileText(fileName: string) {
  try {
    let functionsText = await fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf-8')

    return functionsText
  } catch {
    throw new Error(`'${fileName}' not found`)
  }
}

// export async function getDynamicFunctions() {}
function tryToRemoveExtraText(functionsText: string) {
  try {
    // clean up special characters from file (CRLF, EoF)
    const cleanText = functionsText.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n').trimEnd()
    const normalizedText = replaceAll(
      cleanText,
      prettierSearchTerm,
      legacySearchTerm
    )

    let functionStart = normalizedText.indexOf(legacySearchTerm)
    if (functionStart === -1) {
      throw new Error(
        `No functions found in file.\nThey must have the format of '${legacySearchTerm}' or '${prettierSearchTerm}'`
      )
    }
    return normalizedText.substring(functionStart)
  } catch (err: any) {
    throw errorHandler(err, 'tryToRemoveExtraText')
  }
}
```

The errorHandler function just returns an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `fs.readFile` is not a sync operation not returning anything and it is not a promise.

You could use `fs.readFileSync` instead or use a callback.

Here is a simple example and that's how you could test it

```js
function myFileRead(file): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      return resolve(fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8'));
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e.message);
    }
  });
}

describe('myFileRead',() => {
  it('should resolve', () => {
    jest.spyOn(fs, 'readFileSync').mockReturnValueOnce('File content');

    return expect(myFileRead('./file')).resolves.toBe('File content');
  });

  it('should reject', () => {
    jest.spyOn(fs, 'readFileSync').mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      throw new Error('File not found');
    });

    return expect(myFileRead('')).rejects.toBe(`File not found`);
  });
});
```

When you test a promise whether it rejects or resolves you can use `expect().rejects/resolves` and it returns the promise as well.
Either you need to return it or use `async` context and `await` to it as

```js
it('should reject', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(fs, 'readFileSync').mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      throw new Error('File not found');
    });

    await expect(myFileRead('')).rejects.toBe(`File not found`);
    // Other expect maybe
});
```

Comment: Thanks! How does this change if instead of using just 'fs' I use 'fs/promise'?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use promise then import `fs/promises` and `fs.readFile('/path/to/file, 'utf8').then(...)`